# Create a function with asymmetrical limits

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry

For a software project, I need to create a function that has the following properties:

- $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f(x) = -150$
- $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = 150$

as well as having a "good" scaling so the limit isn't reached until larger numbers of around several thousand.

I can get this working quite nicely by using

$f(x) = \arctan(\frac{x}{a})*\frac{300}{\pi}$

and decided on a "good looking" value of $a = 3500$

But, another requirement stumps my math skills, that needs certain "acceptable" values to already be quite close to the "final" limit:

- $f(-4850) = -149$
- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(9700) = 149$

This would require me to somehow "skew" the function so it's sorta-kinda assymetrical. The only way I would know is to create two functions, one for $x < 0$ and one for $x > 0$, which would be easy enough to do programmatically, but I want to know if there is a way I can manage this in a single one?

Comment: You may want to give more information; the function $x \mapsto 150$ for $x \geq 0$ and $\mapsto -150$ for $x < 0$ has the desired proerty. But this may not be useful for your purpose I guess.

Comment: May I assume a piecewise stitched function would not be acceptable?

Comment: @EricClapton Sorry, I forgot to add a scaling factor that I already implementat so it doesn't slope too quickly. Edited question.

Comment: @Arby I know I can get it done using that, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stretch the function horizontally by doing something like

$$f(x) = \arctan(Kx)*\frac{300}{\pi}$$

and choose a constant $K$ to suit your needs. To stretch it asymmetrically, find a function $K(x)$ that goes to a constant of choice at $+\infty$ and one at $-\infty$ (which you can accomplish using this $\arctan$ function), and do

$$f(x) = \arctan(K(x)x)*\frac{300}{\pi}$$

For a program however I believe using $\arctan$ is far less efficient than a piecewise defined "simpler" function.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure from an efficiency standpoint a piecewise function is  the best. This is basically just to satisfy my math curiosity of how it could be done. I'll play around with your suggestion!

Comment: Isn't searching $K(x)$ the same problem again? If I know how to find that, I would know how to create the actual function I need...?

Comment: No it's not the same problem. $K(x)$ doesn't need to be stretched horizontally, so you could use $$(a-b)\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{\pi}\right)+\frac{a+b}2$$ which goes to $a$ when $x\to\infty$ and to $b$ when $x\to-\infty$. This is enough to stretch $f$ asymetrically, no need to stretch $K$

Answer (score 1):

Find the $x_0$ such that

$$\frac{300}{\pi}\arctan (x_0) = 149.$$

Then consider

$$f(x) = \frac{300}{\pi}\arctan \left ( \frac{12x_0}{5\cdot 9700^3}x^3 -\frac{7x_0}{5\cdot 9700}x\right ).$$

Comment: But that only works for either side of the range, doesn't it?

Comment: Actually I just realized you want $f(0)=0$ as well. Will delete for now

Comment: @FlorianPeschka I think that will work now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 5 years late to this question, but here's another option for anyone else looking for an answer. By modifying the [logistic function](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), you can get $f(x)=\frac{R-L}{1+e^{-C(x-M)}}+L, C\not=0$, where $L=\lim\limits_{x\to -sgn(C)∞},R=\lim\limits_{x\to sgn(C)∞},f(M)=\frac{L+R}2$ and $f'(x)$ is roughly proportional to $C$.

For the example above, $R$ and $L$ can be set to $150$ and $-150$ respectively, and $M$ can be set to the midpoint of $-4850$ and $9700$, which is $2425$. All that's needed is to work out the value of $C$ for which $f(9700)=149$, a task that can easily be done using a function or graphing calculator. For instance, by using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i4h8gmkxhi) to repeatedly refine the upper and lower bounds of $C$ until reaching the limit of the site's precision, ending with ${0.000783566126856}\leq{C}\leq{0.000783566126995}$. This process can be repeated for any variation in the properties specified by the problem.